# Executing JQuery or JS code in evaluate function of Casperjs does not function properly with suggestion fields

Tags: javascript, jquery, phantomjs, casperjs, gui-testing

i have this issue since a few days and could not find a solution. hope you can help me.

I have following login form: imagine the brackets as input fields!

[selectGroup]

[inputUser]

[inputPw]

Select group is a suggestion field. If you enter a char it searches in the db for groups which contain the char and displays ist like a dropdown list.

What I want to do is to click on a suggestion after typing a char with casperjs.

I tried following code in the Browser console and it worked well for me:

```
  //type r into the select group
  document.querySelector('.ember-view.ember-text-field.form-control').value = 'r';


  //focus to input userfield to view suggestions in selectGroup field (normally it is shown without doing a focus but if you do it programmatically you need to focus to view the suggestions)   
  document.querySelector('#inputUser').focus()

  // the selector div.tt-dataset-0 p selcts the first suggestion
 setTimeout(function(){
    document.querySelector('div.tt-dataset-0 p').click()
  }, 200);
```

As mentioned before this results successfully when executing this code in the browser but if I use it in the evaluate function from casperjs it does not work. it only writes r into the suggestion box and does not click a suggestion (i checked it with screenshots).

I first tried solving this problem with the casperjs functions:

```
this.fillSelectors('form#loginForm', {
  '.ember-view.ember-text-field.form-control': 'r'
}, false);

this.mouse.click('div.tt-dataset-0 p');
```

But this functions does not work. And typing the wanted groupname does also not work for logging in due to the fact, that the login requieres some information which are bound to the suggestions.

I tried tried the same with DALEKJS(with phantomjs) (first type r and then click suggestion with a jquery code) and it does work well.

hope this was enough information for you.

cheers izocan

Comment: Have you tried with `waitUntilVisible` until the suggestions appear on screen? http://casperjs.readthedocs.org/en/latest/modules/casper.html#waituntilvisible

Comment: Make sure you wait for the results to appear, also when using jquery to interact with the page while in your evaluate function are you trying to $('#id').click(); ?

Comment: hey guys thanks for your advice, as far as i can judge, the suggestionelement does never appear in the DOM in phantomjs. I get followin error: FAIL "div.tt-dataset-0 p" never appeared in 5000ms
#    type: uncaughtError
#    file: caspertest.js
#    error: "div.tt-dataset-0 p" never appeared in 5000ms

#    stack: not provided
FAIL 15 tests executed in 8.767s, 14 passed, 1 failed, 0 dubious, 0 skipped.

Details for the 1 failed test:

In caspertest.js
  Test KIXOperator Loginpage
    uncaughtError: "div.tt-dataset-0 p" never appeared in 5000ms

Answer (score 0):

Maybe like this :

```
this.sendKeys('.ember-view.ember-text-field.form-control', 'r', {keepFocus: true}); 

casper.waitUntilVisible("your auto-complete div",function(){
    this.click('div.tt-dataset-0 p');
});
```

If you still get the timeout error, try that : :

```
this.sendKeys('.ember-view.ember-text-field.form-control', 'r', {keepFocus: true}); 

casper.wait(1000,function(){
    var fs = require('fs');
    fs.write('results.html', this.getPageContent(), 'w');
    this.capture('checkDropDownList.jpg', undefined, {
        format: 'jpg',
        quality: 75
    });
});
```

And check your html in results.html or that the dropdownlist appears in your screen.

Comment: hey thanks for advice,
what do you mean exactly by **your autocomplete div** i used following code:
    casper.waitUntilVisible("**.tt-suggestion**",function(){
      this.click('div.tt-dataset-0 p');
    });
tt-suggestion is the div for the displayed suggestions. and the element still does not appear in the DOM. I also tried the same thing with div.tt-dataset-0 p and get the same error.

Comment: Well my bad, thought it was an AJAX-auto-complete-. Yes I was speaking about your dropdown list, the div in which the results appear. Did you get the timeout error again?

Comment: yea exactly. it always says sth. like this:

In caspertest.js
  Test KIXOperator Loginpage
    uncaughtError: ".tt-suggestion" never appeared in 5000ms

Comment: hey. you are right the dropdown never appears thats exactly the problem as I thing. but if i check the screenshot. the field for the group is empty (no 'r'). If i check the result.hmtl the dropdownfield for my suggestionfield is **hidden**.

Comment: No 'r'? Then your selector is wrong or not single, complet it. Show us the HTML code if you want. Should work if you can send 'r' and use waitUntilVisible().

Comment: hey dude, the selector must be correct. cuz i can write into the group input field with the same selector when i use the


    this.fillSelectors('form#loginForm', {
      '.ember-view.ember-text-field.form-control': 'r'
    }, true);

the problem was the sendKeys method. idk why. but even though the r is typed the div for the suggestion remains hidden when i check the result.html. also the screenshot of the page like you sent me says that the group field is empty. if i use this.capture after writing the r with the fillselectors method i can see the r. I think that the 'r' is ignored somehow.

Comment: about posting the html: i have to ask my collegeue, cuz this is the code of a company and i am supposed to test it.

Comment: I've never had a problem with sendKeys to fill fields, strange. Does it bug even like that : this.sendKeys('form#loginForm .ember-view.ember-text-field.form-control', 'r', {keepFocus: true}); ? Maybe it's normal you see nothing with fillSelectors(), i'm not sure it keeps the focus by defaut. You still can try it with jQuery using evaluate().

Comment: this.sendKeys('form#loginForm .ember-view.ember-text-field.form-control', 'r', {keepFocus: true}); 
worked well but same result -.-. I tried following code witg jQuery witout success: 

      this.evaluate(function() {

        $('.ember-view.ember-text-field.form-control:first').val('r');
        $('#inputUser').focus();
        setTimeout(function(){
          $('div.tt-dataset-0 p').click();
        }, 200);

        return true;

      });

If i execute the jquery stuff in the Browser it works well but not in the evalate fuction. that was the origin of my post here.

Comment: Aw, ok, does jQuery is already injected or do you inject it with casper? Because if you inject it with casper and it's already injected, you can have some conflicts. Check the case sensitive too, try with 'R'.

Comment: hey, i am not allowed to give away any code of the website. By the way my colleague said, that the html code is generated dynamically--> Ember WebApp. I have also tried the Upper case but same result. I didint inject any jquery but if I do the result is the same. Thanks for your assist.

Comment: Well it's strange, if you can execute it in the browser (jQuery), should work  with Casper and evaluate, maybe you could try it with slimerJS : easier to see the dropdown list appears and debug it.